# How do I remove GTK warnings?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, warnings, gtk3, glade

I'm trying to build a Ruby GUI by using GTK Glade3, but when I'm running my program I get some warnings.

This is the warning:
C:/Ruby/PATS/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.0.7-x86-mingw32/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb: line 551
   GLib-GObject-WARNING **:The property GtkButton:use-stock is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.

I'm using Win-10.

Anyone can help me how to remove those warnings?

[XML code for GtkButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03sUT.jpg)

Comment: Could you post the part of the GtkBuilder XML where this button is created? It seems that it is try to use an old gtk3 function which is deprecated, so based on the XML we can propose a fix.

Comment: Her is the xml code for GtkButton:


http://i.stack.imgur.com/03sUT.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You should modify the GtkBuilder XML to drop the deprecated `GtkButton:use-stock` property, and use a `GtkImage` child widget instead, e.g.:

```xml
<object class="GtkButton" id="back_button">
  <property name="width_request">100</property>
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <child>
    <object class="GtkImage" id="back_button_image">
      <property name="visible">True</property>
      <property name="can_focus">False</property>
      <property name="icon_name">go-previous</property>
    </object>
  </child>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="screen_change" swapped="no"/>
  <style>
    <class name="image-button"/>
  </style>
</object>
```